# How to get an SAS LTO-4 drive to work on a normal PC?

Tags: linux, windows, sata, sas, tape

I got a cheap Tandberg LTO-4 tape drive and I would like to use it on my normal, Windows 10/Ubuntu PC for data backups. I tried a `SAS SFF-8482` to `SATA` adapter, but later found out, that this only works with a SATA Motherboard. I'm using this one though: [MSI B85M-E43 DASH](https://msi.com/Motherboard/B85M-E43-DASH.html#hero-overview) and I have 2 PCIe x1 and a PCI slot free. This is the Drive I want to use: [Tandberg Data LTO-4 HH](http://www.tandbergdata.com/us/index.cfm/products/tape-drives/lto-drives/lto-4-hh/)
I'm thinking that I need a SAS controller, but there is a huge variety and lots of different SAS plugs. Which ones could I use?

The drive does have an SFF-8482 connector.

Comment: What do you mean it only works with a SATA motherboard? You motherboard has 4 SATA connectors? As it's currently a product recommendation this would be off-topic. You would need to find a controller that supports the connector you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to buy PCIe SAS Controller, like this one: LSI SAS3081E-R [ebuy](http://www.ebay.com/itm/LSI-SAS3081E-R-8-port-Internal-SATA-SAS-3Gb-s-RAID-Controller-Card-w-Warranty-/381709868694?hash=item58dfae5e96%3Ag%3A-FYAAOSw4CFYnNpy)
You can plug `LSI-SAS3081E-R` to `PCIe x16` port...
or you can buy something like `Adaptec 6405E` or `PCA-00279-01-B`, to use `PCIe x1` [ebuy](http://www.ebay.com/itm/PCA-00279-01-B-Adaptec-3Gb-s-Dual-SAS-PCI-Ex1-LP-Raid-Controller-AAR-1220SA-/302193411011?hash=item465c2183c3%3Ag%3A-Y4AAOSw9GhYdj5%7E)
To connect this LTO drive to controller - read manual: [LTO-HH SAS Internal Quik Start Guide](http://www.tandbergdata.com/default/assets/File/PDFs/qsg_lto_hh_sas_int_eng3.pdf)
[image]
You don't need nothing else if you already have `SAS SFF-8482` connector cable

Comment: I'd like to add one more thing: If someone else wants to do this, make sure you buy a controller that is certified to work with you drive. It will save you a lot of hassle down the road. Also tape drives work much better with linux using the mt command as opposed to windows. Apart from that, this is actually pretty great for archiving.